# Azure terraform "Endpoint was not set!"

Tags: azure, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

Main.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurestack_resource_group" "demo" {
  name = "k8sample-rg-rg"
}

data "azurestack_subnet" "demo" {
  name                 = "k8sample-rg-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = "k8sample-rg-network"
  resource_group_name  = "k8sample-rg-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "demo" {
  name                = "aathi-sample-aks"
  location             = data.azurestack_resource_group.demo.location
  resource_group_name  = data.azurestack_resource_group.demo.name
  dns_prefix          = "aathi-sample-aks"

  default_node_pool {
    name                = "default"
    node_count          = 2
    vm_size             = "Standard_D2_v2"
    type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    availability_zones  = ["1", "2"]
    enable_auto_scaling = true
    min_count           = 2
    max_count           = 4

    # Required for advanced networking
    vnet_subnet_id = data.azurestack_subnet.demo.id
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "azure"
    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
    network_policy    = "calico"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Development"
  }
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "client_certificate" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.demo.kube_config.0.client_certificate
}

output "kube_config" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.demo.kube_config_raw
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value = data.azurestack_resource_group.demo.name
}

output "resource_group_location" {
  value = data.azurestack_resource_group.demo.location
}

output "subnet_id" {
  value = data.azurestack_subnet.demo.id
}
```

previously I have created the resource group in my Azure portal. I need to consume these resources for my aks cluster. so I have used the data source method. All the resources id are received in the terminal but I am not able to proceed. I am getting the below error.

Comments to reproduce

1. terraform init
2. terraform plan
3. terraform apply

Before this, we need to create a resource group and Vnet with a subnet in AZURE.

```
 resource_group_name  = "k8sample-rg-rg"
 virtual_network_name = "k8sample-rg-network"
  Subnet_name         = "k8sample-rg-subnet"
```

[image]

Comment: What steps do you run to reproduce the above error?

Comment: terraform init


terraform plan


terraform apply

Comment: But resource groups are running in my azure account.

Comment: I am using azurerm and azurestack. please let me know how to use both in the same script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, it seems that you need to register the cloud for the Azure Stack with the CLI command and it will set the endpoint, more details [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurestack/latest/docs/guides/azure_cli). In addition, Azure Stack does not support the AKS cluster, you need to add the service yourself. Take a look at the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-solution-template-kubernetes-cluster-add?view=azs-2008).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right I have used Azurerm and Azurestack in the same file. So I have changed all the code to Azurerm. now it's a working file.

Comment: @AathithaNambi Well, if it works for you please accept it.